# Selenium locate attribute name with space

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently learning Selenium for web scraping. However, I found out problems of locating the following attribute and get the link of the attribute:

`<a class="card cardListing" data-contentid href="/abc/def/gh.com"> == $0`

I want to get the "/abc/def/gh.com" out of the attribute "data-contentid href". I have tried `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@data-contentid href]")`but was told it was an invalid selector.

If there is anybody know how to deal with attribute name with space in the middle, would you mind helping me figure that out?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

First of all its two different attribute `data-contentid` and `href`. And to get a `href = "/abc/def/gh.com"`. you have to use `xpath` as shown below -

Note - in your code you are using `find_elements` and not `find_element`. `find_elements` will return collection of elements.

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href='/abc/def/gh.com']")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! In the target website, there are a list of links under "data-contentid href" I want to get. Indicating "@href" seems to return me with something different from what I want.

Comment: Give it a try - `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@data-contentid and @href='/abc/def/gh.com']")` or `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@data-contentid] and [@href='/abc/def/gh.com']")`

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: If your problem is resolved then please mark it as an answer. So that others will know the issue is resolved.